# import Cython modules in Python files from different packages

Tags: python-3.x, cython, python-import

I created and built a `Cython` file in a separated package from other python packages, the project has the following directory structure,

```
pack1
    pack1.1
        cython_file.pyx
        setup.py
pack2
    main_python.py
```

Along with the `pyx` file, there is also a package called `build` and a `pyd` file been generated after building the `Cython` file.

the `setup.py` looks like,

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize("cython_file.pyx")
)
```

I import `cython_file` in `main.py`, like

```
from pack1.pack1.1.cython_file import cython_func
```

but got an error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'pack1.pack1.1.cython_file'
```

how to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Initially, you should not name a folder `pack1.1`. Using the `.` here will make python search for a package with the name `1` (dots seperate packages in the `import` statement); since Python grammar does not allow names to begin with digits you'll get a syntax error. Opt for a name like `pack1_1`.

Now, trying to `import` from a sibling directory is relatively tricky and not suggested; your best option would be to move the `main_python.py` in the top level directory, if it is the **main** script, it should live there. Your structure should look like:

```
pack1
    pack1_1
        cython_file.pyx
        setup.py
main_python.py
```

Now executing `main_python.py`:

```
from pack1.pack1_1.cython_file import cython_func
cython_func()
```

With a `cython_file.pyx` of:

```
cpdef cython_func():
    print("Cython Function Called")
```

results in the desired result.

---

If you really need to have that directory structure, you'll need to deploy a little trickery by adding the top directory to `sys.path`:

```
import sys, os
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(".."))
from pack1.pack1_1.cython_file import cython_func

cython_func()
```

but this is ugly and you won't find people suggesting it.